# Android Room query limit optional

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I have a method for getting my data from table:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM user LIMIT :limit")
suspend fun getUsers(limit: Int?): List<User>
```

Now I want this behavior:

If I pass 10 for limit I want getUser method return 10 users

If I pass null for limit I want getUser method return all users.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Maybe instead null try assigning -1 as a default argument. A negative value should mean no limit, as stated in SQLite docs https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#limitoffset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I'm trying the function:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM user LIMIT :limit")
suspend fun getUsers(limit: Int?): List<User>
```

It is working just the way I want with null parameter. I don't know why it was not working before.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a new `getUsers` function that doesn't take any parameter and return all users so your code should look like this.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM user LIMIT :limit")
suspend fun getUsers(limit: Int): List<User> // return users with limit number

@Query("SELECT * FROM user")
suspend fun getUsers(): List<User> // return all users
```

Now you can get all the users by calling `getUsers()`

Answer (score 1):

> If I pass null for limit I want getUser method return all users.

If you convert the null into **`-1`** then **LIMIT** will select all rows. So you cold have:-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM user LIMIT :limit")
suspend fun getUsers(limit: Int): List<User>
```

- i.e. no need to accept a null, just pass **`-1`** instead of null.